# MS Word: Macros unavailable in other templates

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-word-2010, templates

I have a bit of an MS Word conundrum here involving macros across multiple templates.

I've created a few macros and saved in Normal.dotm. I'm hoping that, since Normal.dotm is always loaded when MS Word is in use, I can use these macros in any document no matter what the document's template is, Normal.dotm or not. But that's not the case: I can't access the macros when I'm using a document saved with any other template. I know I could just save these macros in the various different templates, but I want to be able to update the macros in only one place.

Is there a way for templates or documents saved from other templates to have access to the macros in Normal.dotm (or any other global templates) without having to load them in to every template?

I should add, in case it's relevant, that these templates are all on the same computer, using the same instance of Word. This isn't over a network or over more than one Windows logon account.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, wow, feel like an idiot. :p I checked my work, and it turns out the problem wasn't with the fact that the macros weren't loading (they were). It just wasn't finding the proper custom properties I put in the template because it was looking at the current template instead of the Normal.dotm template to find these properties it relied on, so it was giving me an error message that didn't make sense until I looked further.

Phew. Onto the next problem!